# Animate a single element ngfor angular without using a variable

Tags: angular, animation, ngfor

I am trying to make a hover and hoverEnd (when the mouse leave the object) effect with Angular but I can't find how to do that. I have tried, without success to make a function that can return true or false. I would like to ask if someone has a better solution to this problem, because I am not sure that using a variable for every element is a good idea.

[myProject](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animationss)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any of your code, this is the best I can come up with

```
hover() {
    const element = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('#element');
    element.addEventListener('hover', () => {
        // do something
    });
    element.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
       // do something else
    })
}
```

then in your `ngOnInit()`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.hover();
}
```

Comment: i dont know how to change the animation state with a function that's the problem i tried with a template variable and the value of the element but it's fine just if you have one element